# Qual a diferença entre form_for e form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Qual a diferença entre `form_for` e `form_tag` na construção de formulários já que o resultado final aparentemente é o mesmo?

Em que situação optar por um ou por outro?

Answer (score 1):

form_for você usa para um model específico, ex

```
<% form_for @user do |f|

<%= f.text_field :nome %>
<%= f.email_field :email %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Form tag vc usa para criar forms simples

```
<%= form_tag '/search' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "q" %>
<% end %>
```